# Press button on website via webBrowser identified by specific form of onclick

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have a problem with click on button on webPage, which have lot of buttons with the same name, but that which I need to press has **onclick="alleyAttack('some ID')"**.

Tell me please how correct fix this part of code.

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
   if (el.GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("alleyAttack(" + listBox1.Items[i] + ")"))
   {
       el.InvokeMember("click");
   }
}
```

Whole **div** with button

```
<div class="button" onclick="alleyAttack(517469);">
   <span class="f">
      <i class="rl"></i>
      <i class="bl"></i>
      <i class="brc"></i>
      <div class="c">
         Fire
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that invokes the click method. What I actually do is the following:

```
(webBrowserElement.Document as HTMLDocument).getElementById("myElement").click();
```

In javascript, you can just invoke the `.click();` and it would work it perfectly, in my project I did it in an actual button, but you can try it.

Comment: I think you can cast it to a IHTMLElement and still make it work.
You could `(el as IHTMLElement).click();`

Comment: could you be more precisely please? as for my case. Thank you

Comment: Change your `InvokeMember` to the code I gave you in the comments. You just need to cast it.